# Small and Cap case in js

Tags: javascript, character, keycode

I have a basic typing tutor built in javascript. It has two portions:
The first portion contains the text/lesson to type and the second portion has keyboard with keys.

I code like this:

```
$(document).on('keyup', function(e){
    if( String.fromCharCode(e.keyCode) == TextCharacter )
        // Character was typed correctly
});
```

The problem is that it works for small case letters. If the lesson contains any character in capital case, it does not work since the user has to type "shift + character".
Is there any way to check if character key is pressed while holding the shift key?

Thanks

Answer (score 0, accepted):

event (e) has two properties to check if shift/ ctrl are pressed. event.shiftKey and event.ctrlKey properties  are set to true if respective key is pressed.

Answer (score 0):

for Shift key, you can use shiftKey:

```
//like
e.shiftKey
```

Answer (score 0):

A quick search for "Javascript keycodes" came up with this: http://www.cambiaresearch.com/articles/15/javascript-char-codes-key-codes

So I guess you'll just detect when shift (keycode 16) and the character is pressed.